# With Delphi and Indy 10.6 I can't find OnWork for TIdServerContext

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

In setting up my TCP Client/Server system, I've subclassed the `TIdServerContext` to add an index flag, but there doesn't seem to be an `OnWork` event.  I need to reset a timer, say while uploading/downloading a large file, and a lot of the Indy components have an `OnWork` event geared for this, but I can't find one for the `TIdServerContext` or `TIdTCPServer`, and the `TIdTCPServer.OnStatus` event appears to be unimplemented, according to other posts.

Here's how I implemented the `TIdServerContext`:

```
TUserContext = Class(TIdServerContext)
Protected
  FUserID: Integer;
Public
  Property UserID: Integer Read FUserID Write FUserID Default 0;
End;

Procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  Server.ContextClass := TUserContext;
End;

Procedure ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
Var
  I: Integer;
Begin
  I := TUserContext(AContext).UserID;
  ...
End;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnWork...` events are in the `TIdComponent` class, which `TIdServerContext` does not derive from.  However, `TIdTCPConnection` and `TIdIOHandler` do.  `TIdContext` has a public `Connection` property, so in your server's events (`OnConnect`, `OnExecute`, etc), you can assign handlers to the `TIdConnection.OnWork...` events as needed:

```
procedure TMyForm.ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.Tag := NativeInt(AContext);
  AContext.Connection.OnWork := WorkHandler;
end;

procedure TMyForm.WorkHandler(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
var
  Ctx: TUserContext;
begin
  Ctx := TUserContext(TIdTCPConnection(ASender).Tag);
  // use Ctx members as needed...
end;
```

Or, another way to pass `AContext` to `WorkHandler` without using `Tag`:

```
procedure TMyForm.ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Handler: TWorkEvent;
begin
  Handler := WorkHandler;
  TMethod(Handler).Data := AContext;
  AContext.Connection.OnWork := Handler;
end;

procedure TMyForm.WorkHandler(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
var
  Ctx: TUserContext;
begin
  Ctx := TUserContext(Self);
  // use Ctx members as needed...
end;
```

Another way to handle this is to override the `TIdServerContext` constructor, which receives the `TIdTCPConnection` object as a parameter.  You could make your handlers be methods of the `TUserContext` class itself, and have its constructor assign the `OnWork...` events immediately, instead of waiting for the server's `On(Connect|OnExecute)` events to fire first:

```
type
  TUserContext = Class(TIdServerContext)
  protected
    FUserID: Integer;
    procedure WorkHandler(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
  public
    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil); override;
    property UserID: Integer read FUserID write FUserID;
  end;

constructor TUserContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  AConnection.OnWork := WorkHandler;
end;

procedure TUserContext.WorkHandler(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  // use Self members as needed...
end;
```

Or, if you just need the event on an as-needed basis:

```
type
  TUserContext = Class(TIdServerContext)
  protected
    FUserID: Integer;
    procedure WorkHandler(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
  public
    procedure StartWorkTimer;
    procedure StopWorkTimer;
    property UserID: Integer read FUserID write FUserID;
  end;

procedure TUserContext.StartWorkTimer;
begin
  Connection.OnWork := WorkHandler;
end;

procedure TUserContext.StopWorkTimer;
begin
  Connection.OnWork := nil;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Ctx: TUserContext;
begin
  Ctx := TUserContext(AContext);

  ...

  if (some condition) then
    Ctx.StartWorkTimer;

  ...

  if (some other condition) then
    Ctx.StopWorkTimer;

  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this I can do, but I'm allowing multiple clients, and each TIdServerContext has the UserID so I know which user is being processed, and each user has their own timer integer I need to reset, so I need to be able to pass the UserID for that Connection to the OnWork event and I'm still a little unclear on that.

Comment: Just make the `OnWork...` handlers be member methods of your `TUserContext` class, that way they are handled per-client, and have access to the `Self` pointer of the `TUserContext` object to access its data members as needed. I updated my answer.